# MDX query to group on year of date dimension with specific date range

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian, mdx-query, rolap

I have SQL query 
SELECT YEAR(DATE),SUM(AMOUNT) FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2018-09-30' GROUP BY YEAR(DATE).

This will give me sum of amount for 2017 and 2018 for selected date range. Same 
I am trying in mdx query with date dimension

SELECT {[Date].[year].CurrentMember*[Measures].[departureUpsellRevenue]} ON COLUMNS,{[Date].[2017].[09].[1]:[Date].[2018].[09].[30]} ON ROWS FROM [CUBE]

its giving me error Mondrian Error:Hierarchy '[Date.calendar]' appears in more than one independent axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try a sub select

```
SELECT 
[Date].[year].[year].MEMBERS ON 0
,[Measures].[departureUpsellRevenue] ON 1
FROM 
(
SELECT
{[Date].[2017].[09].[1]:[Date].[2018].[09].[30]} ON 0
FROM [CUBE]
);
```

Comment: Mondrian Error:Failed to parse query 'SELECT [Date].[year].[year].MEMBERS ON 0,[Measures].[departureUpsellRevenue] ON 1 FROM (SELECT{[Date].[2017].[09].[1]:[Date].[2018].[09].[30]}ON 0 [LocationAndSalesCube]);'

Comment: Mondrian Error:Syntax error at line 1, column 88, token '('

Comment: I missed out the FROM inside the sub select

Comment: same error, I found that mondrian does not support subquery, https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-980

Comment: For solution, i made new dimension of date, One dimension i used in where and another in row.